# I can't view How many megabytes do the images in the project occupy?

Tags: docker, docker-registry, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce

How can I view the Docker image usage information for each project in my locally deployed GitLab instance with an associated Docker registry? I am facing an issue where, upon accessing the user/group project quota settings, the column displaying Docker images consistently shows zeros despite being certain that the images are uploaded. Is it possible that I need to enable a specific setting or perhaps utilize the API to accurately retrieve this information?

I tried to view this information in the used quota, but everywhere it shows 0.